# how to change background color of hamberger

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to change the background color of the hamburger from black to yellow yet no success. 
Here is my attempt:

```js
//hamburger 
$(".hamburger").toggleClass("is-active");
var $hamburger = $(".hamburger");
  $hamburger.on("click", function(e) {
    $hamburger.toggleClass("is-active");
    // Do something else, like open/close menu
  });
```

```css
.hamburger{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jonsuh/hamburgers/0aedeec9/dist/hamburgers.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <button class="hamburger hamburger--emphatic is-active" type="button" id="clickme">
  <span class="hamburger-box">
    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
  </span>
</button>
```

Comment: `button.hamburger { background-color: yellow; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add `!important` to change color, you can target the inner children, by targeting them using a custom parent class(.hamburger class here).

Doing this will override the hamburger.css, without using important class and also keep ur code clean

```
.hamburger1 .hamburger-inner,
.hamburger1 .hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger1 .hamburger-inner::after {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```js
//hamburger 
$(".hamburger1").toggleClass("is-active");
var $hamburger1 = $(".hamburger1");
$hamburger1.on("click", function(e) {
  $hamburger1.toggleClass("is-active");
  // Do something else, like open/close menu
});



//hamburger 

var $hamburger2 = $(".hamburger2");
$hamburger2.on("click", function(e) {
  $hamburger2.toggleClass("is-active");
  // Do something else, like open/close menu
});
```

```css
.hamburger1 .hamburger-inner,
.hamburger1 .hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger1 .hamburger-inner::after {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.hamburger2.is-active .hamburger-inner,
.hamburger2.is-active .hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger2.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jonsuh/hamburgers/0aedeec9/dist/hamburgers.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="hamburger hamburger1 hamburger--emphatic is-active" type="button" id="clickme">
  <span class="hamburger-box">
    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
  </span>
</button>

<h3>If u want on click</h3>

<button class="hamburger hamburger2 hamburger--emphatic " type="button" id="clickme2">
  <span class="hamburger-box">
    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
  </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are loading an external CSS sheet, make sure you add your custom CSS below and include this:

```
.hamburger-inner, 
.hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-inner::after {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

And you should be good to go.